# Getting covariance matrix in Spark Linear Regression

Tags: scala, apache-spark, linear-regression, apache-spark-mllib, covariance

I have been looking into Spark's documentation but still couldn't find how to get covariance matrix after doing linear regression.

Given input training data, I did a very simple linear regression similar to [this](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/ml-classification-regression.html#linear-regression):

```
val lr = new LinearRegression()
val fit = lr.fit(training)
```

Getting regression parameters is as easy as `fit.coefficients` but there seems to be no information on how to get covariance matrix.

And just to clarify, I am looking for function similar to [`vcov`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.4.3/topics/vcov) in R. With this, I should be able to do something like `vcov(fit)` to get the covariance matrix. Any other methods that can help to achieve this are okay too.

---

EDIT

The explanation on how to get covariance matrix from linear regression is discussed in detail [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/68151/how-to-derive-variance-covariance-matrix-of-coefficients-in-linear-regression). Standard deviation is easy to get as it is provided by `fit.summary.meanSsquaredError`. However, the parameter (X'X)<sup>-1</sup> is hard to get. It would be interesting to see if this can be used to somehow calculate the covariance matrix.

Answer (score 3):

Although the whole covariance matrix is **collected** on the [driver](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/ba891ec993c616dc4249fc786c56ea82ed04a827/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/ml/regression/LinearRegression.scala#L606), it is not possible to obtain it without making your own solver. You can do that by copying [WLS](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/561505e2fc290fc2cee3b8464ec49df773dca5eb/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/ml/optim/WeightedLeastSquares.scala#L99) and setting additional "getters".

Closest you can get without digging into the code is `lrModel.summary.coefficientStandardErrors` that is [based](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/ba891ec993c616dc4249fc786c56ea82ed04a827/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/ml/regression/LinearRegression.scala#L959) on diagonal of inverted [matrix](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/561505e2fc290fc2cee3b8464ec49df773dca5eb/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/ml/optim/WeightedLeastSquares.scala#L30) (A^T * W * A) which is [based](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/561505e2fc290fc2cee3b8464ec49df773dca5eb/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/ml/optim/WeightedLeastSquares.scala#L287) on upper triangular matrix (covariance).

I don't think that is enough so sorry about that.

Comment: which part of the code should I copy in WLS? I am okay if I have to modify the code. Also, so is it possible to construct covariance matrix from coefficientStandardErrors?